# CListView Control has limited length for column text

Tags: c++, mfc

When I set the column text for CListView more than 271 characters, the rest of my buffer is not present.

I set it through LV_COLUMN structure.

Is this a known issue for MFC 4.21?

Comment: Alex, thanks for the comment though I accept answers when the questions are answered, like: "This is not possible"; "You can do this with 1, 2, 3". Workarounds are great feedback though not answeting the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's yet another answer you won't like.  It has nothing to do with your *ancient* version of MFC, it is a documented limitation for the list view control.  From the SDK docs for the LVITEM structure's pszText member:

> If the structure receives item
>   attributes, pszText is a pointer to a
>   buffer that receives the item text.
>   **Note that although the list-view control allows any length string to be
>   stored as item text, only the first
>   260 TCHARs are displayed.**

Comment: The answer is bad, for me, bad precise. Thanaks a lot.

Comment: And I do not decide in which framework we should develop, company does :)